# How to determine if Terminal supports ANSI with SBT?

Tags: scala, colors, sbt, ansi-escape

With an old version of SBT I use to do this:

```
initialize := {
  if (sbt.internal.util.ConsoleAppender.formatEnabledInEnv) {
    println("My fancy ANSI long string with color")
  }
}
```

But this is now deprecated at the new SBT requesting the usage of Terminal.isAnsiSupported but I don't know how to access that value.

Maybe with something like this but it triggers an error:

```
initialize := {
  if (terminal.isAnsiSupported) { // <- ERROR
    println("My fancy ANSI long string with color")
  }
}
```

Thanks for any tips and help about this.

Answer (score 0):

OK,found it !! ... after couple of tries is like this:

```
initialize := {
  if (sbt.internal.util.Terminal.console.isAnsiSupported && sbt.internal.util.Terminal.console.isColorEnabled) {
    println("My fancy ANSI long string with color")
  }
}
```

The trick is to use .console inside the internal util Terminal of SBT.